# VB how to hide Drop Down List option?

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, drop-down-menu

Not used to work with VB so I probably missing something obvious

My situation is second:

I have a list of objects. By selecting anything in the drop down, I am loading data on screen

```
ShowFilialData(Me.filialList.SelectedValue)
```

My problem is that I also have a situation, when data are loaded **without drop down help** and it may not be even present inside it. Basically, I am loaded data on screen, but because data wasn't founded inside drop down, drop down picks first one, so some confusion are happening (loaded one thing, but drop down shows that loaded another thing).

To prevent it, in case if data are loaded without drop down, and doesn't exist inside it, I am adding empty item

```
Dim filial As Filial = SelectFilial(filialId)
If Not filial.IsActive Then
  Me.filialList.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem(String.Empty, filialId))
End If
Me.filialList.SelectedValue = filialId
ShowFilialData(filialId)
```

Works fine, I got my empty item in drop down when data are loaded, but **I don't need to see this empty item when I'm opening drop down** (forcing to choose value from list).

Is there a way hide selected item in opened drop down, or is there some kind another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A little addition did the trick for me:

```
Dim emptyItem As ListItem = New ListItem(String.Empty, filialId)
emptyItem.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none")
Me.filialList.Items.Insert(0, emptyItem)
```

Before I tried with `New ListItem(String.Empty, filialId, False)` - was bad idea.